# Proving a line perpendicular to another in a circle

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I got a question at an exam recently, and was unable to solve it.

> Let $\Gamma_1$ be a circle with a chord $CD$ and a diameter $AB\perp CD$ at $N$, with $AN\geq BN$. A circle $\Gamma_2$ is drawn with centre $C$ and radius $CN$. It intersects $\Gamma_1$ at $P,Q$. $PQ$ intersects $CD$ at $M$ and $AC$ at $K$. $NK$ extended meets $\Gamma_2$ at $L$. Prove that $AL\perp PQ$.

Here's the diagram:

[image: Diagram]

I tried various approaches, like proving $AL$ tangent to $\Gamma_2$, Proving $OC||AL$, proving $QP||BF$, proving $QB=PF$, proving $CNAL$ cyclic, all to no avail.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

## Proof

Let $CD$ intersect $\Gamma_2$ at a second point $S$. Notice that $PQ$ is the radical axis of $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$. Thus $$(\overline{CN}+\overline{CM})\cdot(\overline{CN}-\overline{CM}) =\overline{SM}\cdot \overline{MN}=\overline{CM}\cdot \overline{MD}=(\overline{CN}-\overline{MN})\cdot(\overline{CN}+\overline{MN}), $$which implies $$\overline{CM}=\overline{MN}.\tag1$$
Morover, since$$\overline{CK}\cdot\overline{KA}=\overline{NK}\cdot\overline{KL},$$
then $A,N,C,L$ are concyclic. Therefore $$\angle ALC=\angle BNC=90^o,$$ which shows that $AL$ is tangent to $\Gamma_2$. By the symmetry of the tangents $AL,AN$, we may obtain $$\overline{LK}=\overline{KN}.\tag2$$
By $(1),(2)$,we have $$PQ // LC\perp AL.$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $CK\cdot KA=NK\cdot KL$?

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo yes. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeWGR.png)

The diagram shows, $AG \parallel DF$ so $C\hat{F}L = E\hat{A}G = \delta$ and $E\hat{M}F = E\hat{G}A = \gamma$. We can note that $Cl \perp AL$ and $\Delta CLF$ and $CL \perp AL$ then $\gamma + \delta = 90°$

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: I changed. It is more clear, I think

Comment: How is $CL\perp AL$?

Comment: $\Delta ANC$ is similar than $\Delta NKA$ ($K\hat{N}A = 90° - \beta$) than $NK \perp AK$, then $NK = KL$ hence $CL \perp AL$